# Parse JSON in Spark containing reserve character

Tags: apache-spark

I have a JSON *input.txt* file with data as follows:

```
2018-05-30.txt:{"Message":{"eUuid":"6e7d4890-9279-491a-ae4d-70416ef9d42d","schemaVersion":"1.0-AB1","timestamp":1527539376,"id":"XYZ","location":{"dim":{"x":2,"y":-7},"towards":121.0},"source":"a","UniqueId":"test123","code":"del","signature":"xyz","":{},"vel":{"ground":15},"height":{},"next":{"dim":{}},"sub":"del1"}}
2018-05-30.txt:{"Message":{"eUuid":"5e7d4890-9279-491a-ae4d-70416ef9d42d","schemaVersion":"1.0-AB1","timestamp":1627539376,"id":"ABC","location":{"dim":{"x":1,"y":-8},"towards":132.0},"source":"b","UniqueId":"hello123","code":"fra","signature":"abc","":{},"vel":{"ground":16},"height":{},"next":{"dim":{}},"sub":"fra1"}}
.
.
```

I tried to load the JSON into a DataFrame as follows:

```
>>val df = spark.read.json("<full path of input.txt file>")
```

I am receiving

> _corrupt_record

dataframe

I am aware that json character contains "." (2018-05-30.txt) as reserve character which is causing the issue. How may I resolve this?

Comment: Read as RDD, remove the first few characters that are causing the trouble, you'll get a JSON RDD (still `RDD[String]` but with valid n Json), pass it to `spark.read.json` ... Profit

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not a reserved character it is that the file does not contain valid JSON
so you can

```
val df=spark.read.textFile(...)
val json=spark.read.json(df.map(v=>v.drop(15)))

json.printSchema()
root
 |-- Message: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- UniqueId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- eUuid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- location: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- dim: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- x: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- y: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- towards: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- schemaVersion: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- signature: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- source: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sub: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- vel: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ground: long (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  val rdd = sc.textFile("/Users/kishore/abc.json")
  val jsonRdd= rdd.map(x=>x.split("txt:")(1))

  scala> df.show
  +--------------------+
  |             Message|
  +--------------------+
  |[test123,del,6e7d...|
  |[hello123,fra,5e7...|
  +--------------------+




  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
  import sqlContext.implicits._

//  val df = sqlContext.read.json(jsonRdd)
//  df.show(false)


  val df = sqlContext.read.json(jsonRdd).withColumn("eUuid", $"Message"("eUuid"))
    .withColumn("schemaVersion", $"Message"("schemaVersion"))
    .withColumn("timestamp", $"Message"("timestamp"))
    .withColumn("id", $"Message"("id"))
    .withColumn("source", $"Message"("source"))
    .withColumn("UniqueId", $"Message"("UniqueId"))
    .withColumn("location", $"Message"("location"))
    .withColumn("dim", $"location"("dim"))
    .withColumn("x", $"dim"("x"))
    .withColumn("y", $"dim"("y"))
    .drop("dim")
    .withColumn("vel", $"Message"("vel"))
    .withColumn("ground", $"vel"("ground"))
    .withColumn("sub", $"Message"("sub"))
    .drop("Message")

  df.show()

+--------------------+-------------+----------+---+------+--------+------------+---+---+----+------+----+
|               eUuid|schemaVersion| timestamp| id|source|UniqueId|    location|  x|  y| vel|ground| sub|
+--------------------+-------------+----------+---+------+--------+------------+---+---+----+------+----+
|6e7d4890-9279-491...|      1.0-AB1|1527539376|XYZ|     a| test123|[[2,-7],121]|  2| -7|[15]|    15|del1|
+--------------------+-------------+----------+---+------+--------+------------+---+---+----+------+----+
```